# How to make column values to rows in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk, transpose

Below is a sample data in a file

4 columns with TAB separated with last column as values separated by comma.
The 3rd column actually shows number of values in the 4th column.

```
6338838 ESR 3   173812,10547556,10518181
6338822 ESR 2   7219086,12761162
```

Expected output :

```
6338838 ESR 3   173812
6338838 ESR 3   10547556
6338838 ESR 3   10518181
6338822 ESR 2   7219086
6338822 ESR 2   12761162
```

Tried with AWK , but not able to make it work.

Comment: *What* did you try with `awk`?

Comment: There may be duplicates, but the linked one is not one of them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk '{n = split($4,x,","); for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {printf "%s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, x[i]} }' yourfile
```

Comment: I do wonder, sometimes, why the awk community prefers one-liners. Isn't https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/8162e47224e74f564e31859fd14e0901 -- the same code, but formatted such that one can look at the alignment to see where each block and command begins and ends -- far more readable?

Comment: Shell scripts allow literal newlines inside single-quoted strings, so still perfectly pasteable; just need a leading `awk '` line at the beginning and `'` at the end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy When navigating through your local history though, aren't one-liners easier to reuse to e.g. pipe the output through another command?

Comment: In my local history search, up-arrowing into a command with a multi-line literal string shows me... that original command with its multi-line string, whitespace and indentation still intact, and with navigation across line boundaries available for editing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I am somewhat convinced :)

Comment: Heh. Another practice available -- if you want to pipe multi-line chunks of code around, it's probably a good time to encapsulate that code in a shell function anyhow. Throw a `foo() {` on the beginning and a `}` on the end, and then you can `foo | ...` or `... | foo` to your heart's content.

Comment: split returns you the length, just capture it there and use in the for loop.

Comment: `split()` returns the number of fields.

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT:*** How about simply using `gsub` to get rid of commas here :)

```
awk -F" +" '{gsub(",",ORS $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS,$4)} 1' Input_file | column -t
```

Change `-F` to `-F"\t"` in case your Input_file is TAB delimited.

---

---

How about simple using `-F` of `awk` and printing as per fields values.

```
awk -F" +|," '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$2,$3,$i}}'  Input_file
```

Append `| column -t` in above code in case you need TAB delimited output.

As per Cyrus and Ghoti's comment adding following too now in case your Input_file is TAB delimited.

```
awk -F '[\t,]' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i}' Input_file
```

Comment: Nice. Though, beware that the input file is TAB delimited, not space. And instead of piping through `column -t`, you could set your OFS as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: e.g. `awk -F '[\t,]' -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=4; i<=NF; i++) print $1,$2,$3,$i}' file`

Comment: @ghoti, thanks Ghoti yo made my day, Cyrus, sure added this to code now too.

Comment: My goodness, that's a clever approach in your edit. Very nicely done! (And it looks as if it's tied with my second solution as the shorted awk code to produce the desired results.)

Comment: @ghoti, thank you sir :) I will keep this comment save with me to get encouraged every time too.

Comment: Upon reflection, you could shave off six more characters by removing unnecessary spaces: `'{gsub(",",ORS$1OFS$2OFS$3OFS,$4)} 1'`. This definitely gets you top spot for brevity, though it is less readable and might not work in all versions of awk.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {c1to3=$1 FS $2 FS $3; columns=split($4,array,","); for(i=1; i<=columns; i++) print c1to3,array[i]}' file
```

or shorter:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{columns=split($4,array,","); for(i=1; i<=columns; i++) print $1,$2,$3,array[i]}' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} {c=split($4,a,","); NF=3; for(i=1; i<=c; i++) print $0,a[i]}' file
```

Output:

```
6338838 ESR     3       173812
6338838 ESR     3       10547556
6338838 ESR     3       10518181
6338822 ESR     2       7219086
6338822 ESR     2       12761162
```

Comment: Is there anything GNU-specific in this?

Comment: @chepner: I had only tested it with GNU awk.

Answer (score 2):

I love these "who can do it shorter" contests.  :-)

If we cared to use the item count from $3, we could do this:

```
awk '{split($4,a,",");for(i=1;i<=$3;i++){$4=a[i];print}}' OFS='\t' input.txt
```

But the following produces similar results in fewer bytes of code. Output is in the reverse order of subfields in $4.

```
awk '{for(i=split($4,a,",");i;i--){$4=a[i];print}}' OFS='\t' input.txt
```

Not bothering to set `FS` because your sample input doesn't appear to include spaces within the fields.

Answer (score 1):

In native bash:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r one two three four; do
    IFS=, read -r -a pieces <<<"$four"
    for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do
      printf '%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' "$one" "$two" "$three" "$piece"
    done
done <yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `awk`, without referencing to unused fields.

```
$ awk '{n=split($NF,a,","); 
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
          {sub($NF"$",a[i]); 
           print}}' file.t
```